# WMI with Qt examples and info

Tags: c++, qt, wmi

Where can I find more information on and examples of using WMI with Qt?  I have no prior experience with WMI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft have an overview of [how to work with WMI from C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389762(VS.85).aspx). I would start with that and then implement a user interface on top with QT. WMI exposes a [COM interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694363(VS.85).aspx) so you should get familiar with that if you have not used it before. Don Box's Essential COM is one of the better books on the subject.

The Code Project site also has some related [information](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/UsingWMI.aspx). It is generally a good site for C++ programming on Windows.

Are you trying to create a cross-platform app, or do you just target Windows?